# Editable table-valued in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameter-passing

I have an stored procedure with 4 parameters as a table (previosly created as user-defined  table types) and sql management studio force to declare as READ ONLY, but i want to pass this parameters and i want to do update (I have declare some fields nulls for it) some rows, someone can help me?

```
     @TEMP as TEMP READONLY

 The table-valued parameter "@TEMP" must be declared with the READONLY option.
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's not management studio forcing you to declare it read only - it's the rule for SQL Server. If you want a manipulable table, then you need to create a local variable of the same type and copy the rows across.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, they are `READONLY`. Period.

@Damien pointed out a valid workaround: if you want to manipulate the data, you'll need to copy them to an editable structure, such as a table variable or #temp table. Heck, you could even create a separate table type, dump the data there, and manipulate that:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Integers AS TABLE(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ProcessIntegers
  @x dbo.Integers READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @y dbo.Integers;

  INSERT @y SELECT id FROM @x;

  UPDATE @y SET id += 1;

  SELECT id FROM @y;
END
GO

DECLARE @z dbo.Integers;
INSERT @z VALUES(1),(2);
EXEC dbo.ProcessIntegers @x = @z;
```

While there is an additional data copy there, this still gives you the benefits of passing the TVP in the first place, *and* allows you to manipulate it.

Want more background and more details on workarounds? Read [this article by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/tableparam.html) and probably [this one too](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Oh and please comment on and vote for this Connect item, calling for the ability to perform DML against TVPs:

[Connect #299296 : Relax restriction that table parameters must be readonly when SPs call each other](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=299296)